# Internet accessibility of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 without LAN

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

If a company is using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 on-premises using LAN then how can we make CRM accessible to other employees on Internet without LAN using IFD? I tried googling this problem with the help of IFD but couldn't get the desired solution. 
Thanks in advance
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way is usage of IFD. What questions do you have regarding IFD?

Comment: Integration of IFD. How can it be configured? It's lil complicated.

Comment: Moderators do not like url-answers so I just point you. Open youtube and type Microsoft CRM IFD. There are a lot of vieos that in detail describe steps you will have to perform to configure IFD for your CRM.

Comment: Interactivewebs dot com also has a couple of instructions for setting up IFD.